False SD card lock with Canon Powershot G7X Mark 3
When turned on, camera says card write set to lock even though it is not. I've bought new SD cards for it too and it doesn't work. What is the problem?


The "lock" (small grey rectangle on the left side) is a mechanical slider which can be in two positions. It's not connected electrically to anything inside SD card itself. Rather it's the device which accepts the SD card who must detect the position of this switch and disable writing to the card if it's in locked position. Usually this detection is implemented by some metal spring inside the device.
If you did indeed set the cards you inserted to the upper position then it's most logical to suggest that there is slight damage inside your G7X's card slot. It can be easily fixed by somebody skilled without any specialized parts but I'm afraid you cannot do it yourself that easily.

suggestion - highlight specifically on the image where the write-protection switch is
